# Import .ai (illustrator file) in Unity and display them

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg, import, game-engine, adobe-illustrator

I want to load an illustrator file in my game. Unity should recognize different layers, colors, and forms, and layers with text and display them in a 2d canvas.
The goal is that the players can click on different forms and that unity recognize them as individual forms. Do you know any unity asset or a way to make this possible?
For example when you import an image like this as an illustrator file -> https://www.mandala-bilder.de/mandala/erwachsenemandalas/mandala-ideen-erwachsene.pdf
I thought about an SVG file but then I can´t use the different layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator has a proprietary file format, it has no publicly available documentation for newer versions. While you can dig out old specifications (this is why some programs only support AI files saved in ancient versions) http://www.idea2ic.com/File_Formats/Adobe%20Illustrator%20File%20Format.pdf I do not think you can just go in and start supporting a 2021 variant without requesting (and motivating) the spec from Adobe. They might also want to charge you for it.
SVG on the other hand is free and it's spec is public so there is much widely spread support. also SVG supports groups which can get your around the need for layers

Comment: Thank you I didn´t know that. Do you know what I have to tick when exporting the file to have individual layers as a group?

Answer (score 0):

Vector Express is a free conversion API you should be able to use. (requires a network connection, though)

https://github.com/smidyo/vectorexpress-api

You should be able to POST a request (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) to this endpoint, with the raw AI file as the body:

`POST https://vector.express/api/v2/public/convert/ai/gs/pdf/psd2svg/svg/`

This will return a JSON object with a link to an SVG file that you can then download and display.